# Highchart's heat-map plot not rendering correctly when x-axis is in time format (HH:MM)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want to plot a `heatmap` for my data using `highchart` `js` plotting library in R -

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(chron)
library(viridisLite )


fntltp <- JS("function(){
  return this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + this.point.x + ':' + ':<br>' +
  Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.value, 4);
}")

Data = data.frame(Time1 = seq(as.POSIXct('2020-04-30 00:00:00', tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct('2020-05-06 00:00:00', tz = "UTC"), by = '10 min')) %>%
           mutate(Date = paste(substr(weekdays(as.Date(Time1, tz = "UTC")), 1, 3), format(as.Date(Time1, tz = "UTC"), "%b,%d"), " "),
                'Value' = runif(865, -1, 1),
                Time = times(format(Time1, "%H:%M:%S"))) 

hchart(Data, "heatmap", hcaes(x = Time, y = Date, value = Value)) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops(30, rev(viridis(30)))) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(reversed = TRUE, offset = 2, tickLength = 0,
           gridLineWidth = 0, minorGridLineWidth = 0,
           labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "12px"))) %>%
  hc_xAxis(labels = list(type = 'datetime', dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%H:%M'))) %>%
  hc_legend(layout = "vertical", verticalAlign = "middle",
            align = "right", valueDecimals = 0) %>% 
  hc_size(height = 800) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(formatter = fntltp)
```

Clearly this is not the correct plot, when my `x-axis` is formatted in `HH:MM` (in time). Additionally in the `legend` too, the `x-axis` values are not flowing in correctly.

Furthermore, the order of `y-axis` is also not smooth, as I wanted to have the latest day in the bottom and the first day at the top.

Any pointer how to correct those irregularities will be highly helpful.

Modified post based on @raf18seb's reply -

**Below is my new plot with simplified data -**

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(chron)

set.seed(1)
Data = data.frame(Time1 = seq(as.POSIXct('2020-04-30 00:00:00', tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct('2020-05-06 00:00:00', tz = "UTC"), by = '10 min')) %>%
           mutate(Date = paste(substr(weekdays(as.Date(Time1, tz = "UTC")), 1, 3), format(as.Date(Time1, tz = "UTC"), "%b,%d"), " "),
                            'Value' = runif(865, -1, 1),
                    Day_Time = as.character(times(format(Time1, "%H:%M:%S"))))

tail(Data)

hchart(Data, "heatmap", hcaes(x = Day_Time, y = Date, value = Value)) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(reversed = TRUE, offset = 2, tickLength = 0,
           gridLineWidth = 0, minorGridLineWidth = 0,
           labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "12px"))) %>%
  hc_xAxis(labels = list(type = 'datetime', dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%H:%M'))) %>%  
  hc_size(height = 800)
```

**With this I want to achieve below -**

1. In the x-axis, I want to show only `HH:MM` instead of `HH:MM:SS`.
2. The y-axis should be sorted in `increasing order of day`. i.e. May-6 should come at bottom and April-30 should be at top
3. Also want to change the colour gradient i.e. colour should start from `red (for -1)` and end at `green (+1)` with `yellow for midpoint (0)`
4. It would also be good if I can customise the tooltip. Instead of default show here, my ideal tooltip should be `<Value: data-value><br><Date: date as in y-axis><br><Time: Time as in x-axis in HH:MM format>`

Any pointer how to achieve them would be highly helpful

Comment: Hi, I get 2 errors when trying to run your code: Error in as.Date(Time, tz = "UTC") : object 'Time' not found ------------- and ------------Error in hchart(Data, "heatmap", hcaes(x = Time, y = Date, value = Value)) : 
  object 'Data' not found --------------- could you help me with solving them? I should be able to help you with Highcharts when I have a working chart.

Comment: Hi, corrected the code. Many thanks for bringing this into my notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there is a problem with your data.

Explanation:
I managed to get your data out of your R chart. You have 865 points and, after simplifying, your data looks like:

```
{x: 0.00694444444444444, y: 0, value: 0.28064949112013},
{x: 0.0138888888888889, y: 0, value: -0.600626351311803},
{x: 0.0208333333333333, y: 0, value: 0.30516293970868},
...
{x: 0.166666666666667, y: 4, value: -0.619758530985564},
...
```

Your x values are not integers - that is why your chart looks and behaves creepy when you hover over it.

This is a JavaScript simplified demo with your data: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5s3gft6u/
And this is a simple example with decimal x data to help you understand how it behaves: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4j29o3Lh/

So, if I understood your issue correctly, the problem is with your data (x values) and you need to provide different data if you want to make it work in Highcharts. I don't know what data exactly because I don't know what you want to display.

Additionally, you can try with https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.colsize

Maybe setting it to 0.01 will meet your requirement.

**edit to your new requirements:**

1. Again, there is a problem with your data. In JavaScript with proper data, you can format xAxis labels in many ways e.g. having this.value in [labels.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter)
   The problem is that Highcharter (or R) parses your data somehow and this.value is a more complicated object without timestamp value. I don't know how to parse it..
2. Again - your data. You have points April-30 with `y: 0` and May-3 with `y: 1`. In Highcharts, `y` value matters. If you want to have a proper order, then you need to parse your data and match the proper date with `y`.
3. You can use [tooltip.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) to define whatever you want to display in the tooltip

Comment: Many thanks for your analyses. I further modified the original post with a simplified version of my original graph. Also tried to clarify more what I would like to achieve. Please ket me know if those suffice

Comment: I edited my answer. In general, your data is still in a strange format